# Error while creating azure blob SAS token from react app "Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid"

Tags: reactjs, azure, blob, sas-token

I am trying to create a sas token from react app

```
async function GenerateSASToken() {
    const sasUrl = `https://${accountname}.blob.core.windows.net?sv=2021-06-08&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-02-20T16:01:34Z&st=2023-02-20T08:01:34Z&spr=https&sig=<signinkey>`;
    axios.get(sasUrl)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log('SUCCESS');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('FAIL');
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

But I am getting error while calling endpoint as

**400 (Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.)**

Comment: Note: I have taken sasUrl from Azure portal while we manually generate token.

Comment: You are using the SAS token. What operation in Azure Storage are you trying to do with this?

Comment: If you are using get method try post method instead of the get method and check you still getting the same error

Comment: @GauravMantri I am trying to download blob. But generating token itself failing

Comment: Any idea how we generate 'sig' parameter value in sas url?

Comment: @vijaya post is not supoorted

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are using incorrect URL.

If you want to download a blob, the URL should be something like `https://${accountname}.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-name>?sv=2021-06-08&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-02-20T16:01:34Z&st=2023-02-20T08:01:34Z&spr=https&sig=<signinkey>`.

The URL you are using corresponds to [`Get Account Information`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-account-information?tabs=shared-access-signatures) which requires `restype=account&comp=properties` URL parameters. Since you are not including these parameters in your URL, you are getting 400 error.

**UPDATE**

If you are trying to generate a new SAS token, please note that:

- There is no REST API endpoint to generate an Account or Service SAS token. Please read the documentation here about how you can generate a SAS token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature.
- You cannot generate a new SAS token using another SAS token.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Gaurav but my scenario is, I have UI which downloads blob. I have completed code to download blob using SAS token (which I generated from portal) like

https://${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net${SAS_TOKEN}

But here instead of getting token from portal and updating it in code everytime it expires is not a solution so i want to generate sas token programmatically.  How can I do it?

Comment: In this case you would need an API endpoint which will return you a SAS token. You will then need to use SAS token to download the blob.

Comment: Ok But How will API generate sas token?

Comment: You can use Azure Storage SDK in your API code to generate the token.